# How can I get a link containing 15 digits from url using javascript in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Iam trying to get a link from the server using url.But Iam getting an error as:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.2.64:4000/link. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:36148' is therefore not allowed access.

How can I get the link from the server using javascript?How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Plenty of dupes on CORS/Same Origin Policy - different port = different domain

Comment: You could ask the server administrator to allow it

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource